# RecycleView doesn't initialse

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I've got an activity with recycleview in it. When activity launches it throws me NPE on this recycle view. And I can't understand why.

Here is onCreate method where it is init:

```
    protected void onCreate (@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.chat_window_activity);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById (R.id.recycleview);//here is null
        messagesList = Controllers.getMessagesForSingleNumberFromDB (tableName, getApplicationContext ());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager (new LinearLayoutManager (this)); //logs pointing to this line, but I think that problem not here.
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new ChatWindowRecycleAdapter ( new ChatWindow(), messagesList); 
        recyclerView.setAdapter (adapter);
    }
```

Also xml where it used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleview"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sendInputMessageLayout">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sendInputMessageLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        //Some views

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Debugger saying that  `recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById (R.id.recycleview);` is null and when I checking if it's null by invoking `recyclerView == null` it returns false. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure xml you provided here is chat_window_activity.xml ?

Comment: No, and it was a place where this problem was, thanks!